# I am altering the CSS value from JavaScript but for some reason it does to take the variables

Tags: jquery

I know this is simple but the variables value from the jQuery/JavaScript is not taken by #full_body div. Below is the code.

Default CSS:

```
body{background-color: #fff; background-color: #b9770e; color:#fff;}
```

Any help would be appreciated .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#full_body').css(width: '1900');
    $('#full_body').css(height: '1200');
    $('#full_body').css({
      'background-color': '#fff'
    });
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
</head>

<div id="full_body">
  test
  <script language="javascript">
    document.write(h);
    document.write("\n");
    document.write(w);
  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `$('#full_body').css('width', '1900');`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Tried that, does not work

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question, if it sounds simple get me it working for me, if theres a solution provide it.

Comment: Try look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/da9uw4og/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I changed it to my code and its not working, check the jsfiddle

Comment: check what fiddle?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes pls

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
</head>
<div id="full_body">
    test
   

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#full_body').css("width", "1900");
    $('#full_body').css("height", "1200");
    $('#full_body').css("background-color", "yellow");
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no reason for him to change from Id to class

Comment: Your solution is not working for me.  @CarstenLøvboAndersen I was wondering the same

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple property using single `.css` method like below. No need to add multiple times.

```js
$('#full_body').css({
  'width': '1900',
  'height': '1200',
  'background-color': '#fff'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js">
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
</head>
<div id="full_body">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: check: https://jsfiddle.net/Lugsaoh8/1/  - can you explain why it does not work?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, it works on jsfiddle and do not why my altered code does not work on my system.  Anyway I copy/paste your code and it works fine.  Thanks mate